# No module named 'chaterbot'

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, python-3.8, chatterbot

I was trying to do a tutorial on youtube, when i ran the code visual studio selects line 3 and I can read: Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'chaterbot'
I have chatterbot 1.0.4 installed, i'll leave the code below for anyone who could help me, thank you for your help.

Code:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
bot = ChatBot(
    'Eustaquio',
    storage_adapter="chaterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
    logic_adapter=[
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter',
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation'
    ],
    input_adapters="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",
    output_adapter="chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter",
    database = './tutorial'
)

while True:
    boti = bot.get_response(None)
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
bot = ChatBot(
    'Eustaquio',
    storage_adapter="chaterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
    logic_adapter=[
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter',
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation'
    ],
    input_adapters="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",
    output_adapter="chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter",
    database = './tutorial'
)

while True:
    boti = bot.get_response(None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not *"chaterbot"*. It's *"chatterbot"* (line 4)

Comment: Thanks I didn't saw it, i revised the code too but, I'm a little blind xd